# Filtering products using custom attributes in magento2 with graphql causes error: Field is not defined by type ProductAttributeFilterInput

Tags: filter, graphql, magento2, custom-attributes

I'm trying to filter products retrieved from my backend magento2 with custom attributes using graphql query as mentioned in official documentation:[https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/custom-filters.htm]
using attribute_code: "color" which exists as a custom attribute but that gave me the following error in postman: **"Field "color" is not defined by type ProductAttributeFilterInput."**

here is my query:    `{
products(filter: {

```
 color: { eq: "4677" } }) {
total_count
items {
  name
  sku
  price
}
```

}
}`

I'm using magento 2.3.4

[error in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV0sN.png)

I would be grateful if someone could help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the error message I can understand that the color field is not declared in the ProductAttributeFilterInput. Please check the schema.graphqls file again and make sure the fields you want are declared properly